# Event Bubbling from update Panel

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

When you do an update with update panel I loose all my jquery elements that attached them too the elements of the DOM inside the update panel. Is there a way to reattach these when update panel fires?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Update Panel stops jquery from working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207206/asp-net-update-panel-stops-jquery-from-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the elements you had previously attached functions to are replaced by new elements by the ASP.NET update panel. Consider using jQuery's [live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) utility function.